# How to use ls command from module?

Tags: linux, kernel

I want to run the commands like ls,cd,cat from my module.
Actually I want to run this command ls >> file.txt which makes a text file in that directory and save all the fle names in this text file...
How can I do this??

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `from my module`? what module is this? Do you mean running this command from your script?

Comment: Actually I want to take input from file in my module. For that purpose, I want all the file names in a single text file. When I use this command(ls >> file.txt) in terminal it works fine and I want to do this from module...

Comment: You're talking about _kernel modules_ (as illustrated by your code quote below using `filp_open()` which is a _kernel function_). The answer is, no you can't just "spawn" userspace programs from within the kernel in a simple fashion. In that sense, please clarify your question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Yes, I am talking about kernel modules. I want to read a file from my module and when I tried to do that without (ls -l > input.txt) command or reading another file it works fine. But I want to make a file in that directory and reading that file from my module. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what do you mean by `from my module` but assuming that from within your script you want to run `ls` command then you can do so like

```
`ls -l > input.txt`
```

Comment: It generates a warning.
warning: statement with no effect

Comment: have you checked whether it generated the file `input.txt` with required output.

Comment: Yes it generates the file in that directory..
But why this warning occurs?

Comment: I open a file using this. Am I correct or wrong ??
f = filp_open("input.txt", O_RDONLY, 0);

Comment: You are just storing the output of the command in file not doing anything else (like storing it a variable or so) and hence that warning (means statement has no effect). Are you trying to open the file in shell script or some other programe?

Comment: I open a file using this. Am I correct or wrong ??
f = filp_open("input.txt", O_RDONLY, 0);

Comment: Unfortunately, no idea.

Comment: @MuhammadNouman, if this answer helped you then try accepting it as answer.